# How to find rows that differ by only one column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, with three columns. I have grouped them based on two of the 3 columns. Now I need to find only those rows where the two columns `word1,word2` are same but the column `Tag`,the third column, is different.

This something like I need to find those columns, where for the same `word1 and word2` we have different labels. But I am not able to filter the dataFrame based on the groupby construct shown below

```
newComps.groupby(['word1','word2']).count()
```

[image]

Here it wil lbe helpful if I can see only the ones with same word1,word2 but with a different Tag, rather than all the entries. I have tried with calling the above code inside `[]`, as we use to filter the data, but to no avail

Ideally I should see only

```
A,gawam, A1
A,gawam,BS1
A,gawaH, T1
A, gawaH, T2
```

Comment: Please dont use png for data or code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

look at the `subset` and the `keep` option

Comment: If I had to drop the duplicates without looking into the data, I could have done it. But here I need to view those entries, rather than dropping them

Comment: here we go http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html